# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ci')

Tags: angular

Por favor necesito ayuda, quiero crear un formulario en angular pero al poner el [ngModel] no lo reconoce y lo manda indefinido, no puedo guardar ningun dato por que me sale este erro, cabe recalcar que si me imprime en una tabla, pero no me deja crear en angular, en mi Api de spring boot  si lo hace correctamente

module

export class Cuenta {

```
idCuenta!:number;
email!:string;
fechaCreacion!:Date;
contrasena!:string; 
usuario!:Usuario;
rol!:Rol;
```

}

cuenta.service

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

 import { Cuenta } from '../models/cuenta';

 import { Rol } from '../models/rol';

 import { Usuario } from '../models/usuario';
```

@Injectable({

```
   providedIn: 'root'

 })

export class CuentaService {

     private url:string="http://localhost:8088/geolib/cuentas";

     constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

     create(cuenta:Cuenta):Observable<Cuenta>{

      return this.http.post<Cuenta>(this.url,cuenta);
  
 }

 getAll():Observable<Cuenta[]>{ 

   return this.http.get<Cuenta[]>(this.url)};
```

en el cuenta.service e visto que utilizan tanto get como post para crear un nuevo usuario

COMPONENT

```
  export class UsuarioFormsComponent implements OnInit {

       cuenta:Cuenta= new Cuenta();

        constructor(private cuentaServicio:CuentaService, private router:Router) { 

      }

     ngOnInit():void{

      }

     create():void{

       console.log(this.cuenta);}
```

HTML

```
    <form>

       <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="ci" class="form-label">Cedula</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ci"[(ngModel)] = 
                                                               "cuenta.usuario.ci">
            </div>    
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleInputNombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputNombre"[(ngModel)] = "cuenta.usuario.nombres">
              </div>   
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputApellido" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputApellido"[(ngModel)] = "cuenta.usuario.apellidos">
                </div>         
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"[(ngModel)] = "cuenta.email">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputTelefono" class="form-label">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTelefono"[(ngModel)] = "cuenta.usuario.telefono">
                </div>
  </form>
```

no entiendo por que me sale el error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ci') por que estoy guiandome con un video pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente es porque te falta iniciar usuario dentro de cuenta:

```js
cuenta:Cuenta= new Cuenta();

this.cuenta.usuario = new Usuario();
```

O bien puedes inicializarlo en el modelo:

```js
export class Cuenta {
    constructor() {
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }
    idCuenta!: number;
    email!: string;
    fechaCreacion!: Date;
    contrasena!: string;
    usuario!: Usuario;
    rol!: string;
}
```

Comment: si era, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).